# Bedeutung von "fair"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, english-to-german, difference

Ich habe das Wort "fair" in mein Wörterbuch hinzugefügt, nachdem ich aus [Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/fair) geschlussfolgert hatte, das es dem englischen "fair" entspricht (es wurde 10k+ Male als die Übersetzung verwendet, während die anderen angegebenen Übersetzungen gar nicht passen). Trotzdem habe ich gemerkt, dass seine Definitionen laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fair) und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fair) anders als beim englischen Wort sind, "den Regeln des Zusammenlebens entsprechend; anständig, gerecht im Verhalten gegenüber anderen" und "anständig in seinem Verhalten anderen gegenüber" jeweils. Oder ich irre mich und es bedeutet auch, dass man jemanden richtig behandelt und nicht zulässt, dass persönliche Meinungen sein Urteil beeinflussen?

Comment: Wenn ich im En<>De Wörterbuch nachschaue, ist diese Auslegung von "fair" exakt die Deutsche Übersetzung des englischen "fair". Wo siehst du denn Unterschiede zwischen Englisch und Deutsch bei diesem Wort?

Comment: Nicht zuzulassen, daß "persönliche Meinungen sein Urteil beeinflussen" wird mit dem Wort "objektiv" ausgedrückt. Entscheidungen können aber *objektiv unfair*, *objektiv fair* oder auch *subjektiv fair/unfair* sein, das eine hat also mit dem anderen also nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 5):

Das im Deutschen verwendete "fair" entspricht dem englischen "fair" im Sinne von "gerecht/angemessen/anständig".

Beispiele wären "fairer Lohn", "faires Verhalten", "das ist fair".

Allerdings hat "fair" im Englischen noch andere Bedeutungen z.B. "schön" ("My Fair Lady"). Diese Bedeutungen sind den meisten Deutschen aus dem Englischen unbekannt und sind daher auch nicht gemeint, wenn ein Deutscher sagt "fair".

Answer (score 1):

Das deutsche Lehnwort *fair* entspricht in etwa dem Ausdruck *nach den Regeln.*

Comment: Ich weiss nicht, etwas kann "fair" aber nicht nach den Regeln sein, oder unfair aber regelkonform. Tatsächlich würde ich im Sport "unfair" als völlig unabhängig von den Regeln betrachten. Wäre es gegen die Regeln, wäre es nicht "unfair", sondern ein Foul. Man kann fair spielen und Fouls begehen und völlig Regelkonform unfair sein.

Comment: @nvoigt Ich würde sogar noch weiter gehen. Es gibt zum Beispiel immer wieder Diskussionen darüber, ob Regeln, Regelungen oder Gesetze selbst _fair_ oder _unfair_ sind. Siehe z. B. [Warum die bisherige Regelung unfair ist](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/wirtschaft/bundesregierung-will-millionen-mieter-entlasten-6853549.html) (im Kontext von Heizkosten) oder [Dass diese Regelung unfair ist, ...](https://www.deutsche-apotheker-zeitung.de/news/artikel/2016/10/24/diese-preismodelle-werden-diskutiert) (im Kontext von Versandapotheken).